# Synchronization of processes

Tags: .net, process, synchronization, mutex

For example, I create two processes (ConsoleApplication2.exe). Each of them writes the some text ("dog" or "cat") into the same text file: c:_threads_laboratory\data.txt. I want to get a result:

> dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>   cat 
>  ... 
>  dog 
>  cat

but I get this:

> dog 
>  dog 
>  dog 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>   dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>  cat 
>  dog 
>   cat 
>  ...

Why I get incorrect result? How can I fix it?

My processes are launched by the Launcher.exe:

```
// Program.cs
// It builds the Launcher.exe
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Launcher {

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      Console.Title = "Launcher";
      String fileFullName = @"c:\_threads_laboratory\data.txt";

      using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "my_mutex")) {

        if (File.Exists(fileFullName))
          File.Delete(fileFullName);

        Process proc_1 = new Process();
        String exeName = @".\ConsoleApplication2.exe";
        ProcessStartInfo info_1 = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName, "proc_#1 dog");
        proc_1.StartInfo = info_1;
        proc_1.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("proc_#1 started by launcher...");

        Process proc_2 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info_2 = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName, "proc_#2 cat");
        proc_2.StartInfo = info_2;
        proc_2.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("proc #2 started by launcher...");

        mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        proc_1.WaitForExit();
        proc_2.WaitForExit();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Result in the \"{0}\" file.", fileFullName);
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

ConsoleApplication2.exe code:

```
// Program_2.cs
// It builds the ConsoleApplication2.exe
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2 {

  class Program_2 {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      if (2 != args.Length)
        return;

      Console.Title = args[0];

      Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "my_mutex");

      String dir = @"c:\_threads_laboratory";
      String file = "data.txt";
      String fullName = Path.Combine(dir, file);
      if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
      String text = args[1];
      Int32 counter = 100;

      using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fullName, FileMode.Append,
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
          while (counter-- > 0) {
            mutex.WaitOne();
            fs.Position = fs.Length;
            sw.WriteLine(text);
            Console.Write("*");
            sw.Flush();
            fs.Flush(true);
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            Thread.Sleep(0);
          }
          sw.Close();
        }
        fs.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect any synchronization at all? The result should be totally random.

Comment: because I use the named mutex for process synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing Mutexes and Events. "Mutex" is short for "Mutually Exclusive" - your code only ensures that two process won't write to the file on the same time.

What you really want is two events; a way for one process to signal that it is done and now waiting for the other - and another event for the other way around.

Comment: "Please note that events in Windows are not totally safe from race conditions." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Named mutexes can be used for synchronization not the threads  only, but the processes also (The reference book on C#4.0 Herbert Schildt).

Answer (score 0):

You got synchronization.  An unsynchronized result would have been something like

```
docat
g
cat
cat
cadto
g
dog
catdog

cat
```

Comment: No. Look attentively at the text file beginning.

Comment: @Bush: You completely missed the difference.  In your example, the outputs are never interleaved.